# Can the same version support multiple routing path?

Tags: docusaurus

Can the same version support multiple routing path

```
versions: {
            current: {
              path: '1.1.2',
            },
            '1.1.1': {
              path: 'latest',
            },
          }
```

The current latest version is 1.1.1 (latest), which can be accessed through https://linkis.apache.org/docs/latest/introduction,

Is there a configuration that supports both correct access via https://linkis.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/introduction

Comment: I copied the `1.1.1` versioned files to a version named `latest` to solve it